# How do I bind CMD+W to kill the current buffer in Emacs on OSX?

Tags: mac, emacs, elisp

How do I bind CMD+W to kill the current buffer in Emacs on OSX? C-x k RET is unnatural and a comparatively lengthy binding compared to CMD+W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun kill-current-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-w") 'kill-current-buffer)
```

(Credit goes to `jlf` at #emacs)